# Format XML so that attributes align vertically

Tags: java, xml, transform

I wanted to find out if there was any way to be able to format an XML document that I have generated so that the attributes align vertically? Below is a snippet of the transform method that I have written.

I am creating the Element this way:

```
    Element element = document.createElement(elementName);
    element.setAttribute("name", nameAttribute);
    element.setAttribute("id", idAttribute);
    element.setAttribute("val", valAttribute);
```

They are then added to the document ready for transformation.

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;

    try {
        transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        File file = new File(fileName);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am able to get the indentation working, but I also want to know if there is any way to pad the attributes so that they line up underneath each other.

Currently it looks like:

```
<ref name="message" type="message.sender">
    <p id="1" name="BeginString" val="${BeginString}"/>
    <p id="36" name="Message" val="${Message}"/>
    <p id="42" name="Sender" val="${Sender}"/>
    <p id="73" name="SendingTime" val="${SendingTime}"/>
    <p id="1134" name="Target" val="${Target}"/>
</ref>
```

However I would like to have it formatted like this.

```
<ref name="message" type="message.sender">
    <p id="1"     name="BeginString" val="${BeginString}"/>
    <p id="36"    name="Message"     val="${Message}"/>
    <p id="42"    name="Sender"      val="${Sender}"/>
    <p id="73"    name="SendingTime" val="${SendingTime}"/>
    <p id="1134"  name="Target"      val="${Target}"/>
</ref>
```

My only reason for doing so is that in longer files it makes the content easier to read and the program will be given to less techie people as well.

Thanks

Comment: There is a way. Write the XML text yourself *(not recommended)*.

Comment: @Andreas my predecessor already did to get it working and I unfortunately, now need to live with the consequences. I have lines that look like this

`writer.write("        <const name=\"Name\"              val=\"${" + sessionName + ".Name}\"/>\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen such functionality in an XML library.

If your document has only the structure you show it would be relatively easy to serialize as you like creating a custom [ContentHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) that prints the XML as you want. Just extend [DefaultHandler](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) and implement `startElement` and `endElement` to print the `ref` and `p` elements. Use a library to XML-escape the attribute values. Then parse the document with the XMLReader obtained by an [XMLReaderFactory](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLReaderFactory.html) and configured with the custom ContentHandler to trigger the events and print the document. It will also be much much faster than TrAX.

I would not normally reccomend to do this but if it really helps in enabling non techie to do things and leave developers alone then go for it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will have brief look and if it looks like more than 10 mins work, users will just have to live with the format.

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR*** - There's nothing in any standard or library that does this.

XML is intended for consumption by a *program*, not a human.  As such, non-significant spaces are exactly that, non-significant, and the serializer is not required or expected to do anything special with them, or provide any options to pretty-print them.  Especially with regards to coordinating spacing of attributes between *different* tags.

You could, in theory, provide your own serializer but this would be a lot of work and you'd have to decide what constitutes adjacent tags that need to have their attributes aligned, what happens when attribute order is different, etc, etc, etc.  You'd always end up with situations you don't quite handle "right".

In short, there's nothing standard that would accomplish what you want, and writing code to do it would IMHO be a waste of time.

Comment: I know that XML is designed for consumption by a program, however when well formatted it can be easy for humans to digest as well.
Unfortunately a precedent has been set that I know have to follow and utilising existing libraries is much nicer than spending a couple of hours writing writer.write() to append the file.
Also as I developer I thought our role was to assist the end user when using our programs and making XML more readable is one small way of achieving that. At least in this case.